# External CSS doesn't work on Edge 2017 build and IE11

Tags: css

The CSS works perfectly on any other browser, even on the newer version of edge. But since I am stuck on the 2017 build, it just doesn't want to be linked. I have tried on ie11 as well but still the same results.
Here is the CSS:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: century gothic;
}

header {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url(../cyber.gif);
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

ul{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.1%;
    right: 5%;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top:  25px;
}

ul li{
    display: inline-block;
}

ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: none;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
}

ul li a:hover{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}

ul li.active a{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}

.logo img{
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: auto;
}

.main{
    max-width: 1200px
    margin: auto;
}

.search-box{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5.5%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: #2f3640;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.search-btn{
    color: #6C92C8;
    float: right;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #2f3640;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.search-txt{
    border: none;
    background: none;
    outline: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 25px;
    width: 240px;
}
```

It isn't a cache problem as I already tried that. Not too sure on what to do..

Comment: its not a css issue its a browser issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out your external css link